# Is it me or jsfiddle that is messing up here?

Tags: jsfiddle

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Mzf7P/)

translates into [this page](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Mzf7P/show/)

Which gives me a script looking like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<sels.length="";i=""++) {
  if="" (sels=""[i=""].name="".indexOf=""("-Car=""") != -1="") {
    IDs="".push=""(sels=""[i=""].name="".split=""("-")[0=""]);
  }
}
form="".onsubmit="function()" {
  var="" atLeastOne="false,id,error="",fieldToFocus;"
  for="" (var="" i="0;i<IDs.length;i++)" {
    id="IDs[i];"
    var="" sel1="this.elements[id+"-Car"];"
    var="" sel2="this.elements[id+"-AgeGroup"];"
```

I am editing on my iPad so I have a hard time seeing where the issue is.

I know it is a localised issues, so apologies if it is off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like this, so all is fine:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

    window.onload=function() {
      var IDs = [],
      form = document.getElementById("form1"),
      sels = form.getElementsByTagName("select");
```

Comment: Thanks, must hae been some temporary glitch on their or my side.